# Date Format in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

my data is curently in this format

> head(month)
>   [1] "192512" "192601" "192602" "192603" "192604" "192605

means 1925 Dec, 1926 Jan, etc

How do I convert this value to "Dec1925"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as.POSIXct` function for all kinds of date manipulations, these are well worth investigating. Unfortunately without a day included in the date, this returns `NA`. So, to use it you can first append some day "01" to the end of your number strings. Then, when reformatting to character, the day can be dropped again.

```
as.character(as.POSIXct(paste0(month,'01'),format='%Y%m%d'),format = '%b%Y')
```

You can use `?as.POSIXct` to see more about the `as.POSIXct` function.

`?strptime` will give you a listing of all the format options.